# SSIS to Azure HDInsight Using Microsoft Hive ODBC Driver

Tags: azure, hadoop, ssis, odbc, azure-hdinsight

Currently driving an RnD project testing hard against Azure's HDInsight Hadoop service. We use SQL Server Integration Services to manage ETL workflows, and so making HDInsight work with SSIS is a must.

I've had good success with a few of the [Azure Feature Pack tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt146770%28v=sql.120%29.aspx). But there is no native HDInsight/Hadoop Destination task for use with DFTs.

#### Problem With Microsoft's Hive ODBC Driver Within An SSIS DFT

I create a DFT with a simple SQL Server "OLE DB Source" pointing to the cluster with a "ODBC Destination" using [Microsoft HIVE ODBC Driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40886). (Ignore red error. It has detected the cluster is destroyed).

[image]

I've tested the cluster ODBC connection after entering all parameters, and it tests "OK". It is able to read the HIVE table even and map all columns to. The problem arrives at run time.

It generally just locks up, with no rows in counter, or it will get to a handful of rows in the buffer and freeze.

I've troubleshooted with:

- Verified connection string and Hadoop cluster username/password.
- Recreated cluster and task several times.
- Source is SQL Server, and runs fine if I point it to only a file destination or recordset destination.
- Tested a smaller number off rows to see if it is a simple performance issue (`SELECT TOP 100 FROM stupidTable`). Also tested with only 4 columns.
- Tested on a separate workstation to make sure it wasn't related to the machine.

I can't figure out what else to try. I'm not doing much different than examples on the web like this [one](http://www.mattmasson.com/2013/11/using-hive-odbc-from-ssis/), except that I'm using the ODBC as a Destination and not a Source.

Has anyone had success with using the HIVE driver or another one within an SSIS Destination task?

Comment: Hey Jon, are you able to enable logging within the driver and attach a trace when it seems to hang? Also, which version of the driver are you using? Do you see the issue if you're using a separate app such as Excel?